# image_dim_ordering - what am I missing here?

Tags: keras

EDIT: Could not reproduce this issue using cuda 8.0 and using titan X (Pascal)

Using tensorflow backend for keras I have issues that are related to image_dim_ordering.
When I use image_dim_ordering='th' in the keras config file, everything works well But when I use 'tf', training simply doesn't really improve much from 0.5 accuracy.

The motivation is that currently my live augmentations are very costly, and I'd love to remove the unneeded reshape from theano dim order convention to tensorflow.

I tried recreating the issue with simple  code to allow reproduction by other people which may assist me to  understand what am I doing wrong here. I'm well aware of the channel,height,width different conventions, and at least I think that I handle that.

While I didn't fully reproduce my problem in the compact example (maybe because it's a trivial task), the training results are repeatedly different, and much worse for the 'tf' case, even when I try different seed values.
Note - in this reproducing code, all that the network needs to do is to tell apart full patches of -1.0 from full patches of 1.0

This is my '~/.keras/keras.json'

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_dim_ordering": "th"  
}
```

my tensorflow version is ''0.11.0rc0'' (it happened on 0,10 as well)
my keras is latest git pull of today.

Using 'th' for the image_dim_ordering I get accuracy >=0.99 at epoch 4 for three different seeds.
Using 'tf' for the dim order I get accuracy >= 0.9 much latest as you can see below in the log, only at around epoch 24

**The following is a standalone code that should reproduce the problem:**

```
from keras import backend as K
import keras.optimizers
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

def make_model(input_dim_size):
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':
        input_shape = (input_dim_size, input_dim_size,1)
    else:
        input_shape = (1, input_dim_size, input_dim_size)
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = Convolution2D(64,5,5,border_mode='same')(img_input)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2))(x)

    x = Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, border_mode='same')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, border_mode='same')(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(1024*2)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = Dense(1024 * 2)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.75)(x)

    x = Dense(200)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.75)(x)

    x = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(img_input, x)

    learning_rate = 0.01

    sgd = keras.optimizers.sgd(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=sgd,
                  metrics=['accuracy']
                  )
    return model

np.random.seed(456)

def dummy_generator(mini_batch_size=64, block_size=100):
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':
        tensor_X_shape = (mini_batch_size,block_size, block_size,1)
    else:
        tensor_X_shape = (mini_batch_size, 1, block_size, block_size)

    X = np.zeros(tensor_X_shape, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.zeros((mini_batch_size, 1))

    while True:
        for b in range(mini_batch_size):
            X[b, :, :, :] = (float(b % 2) * 2.0) - 1.0
            y[b, :] = float(b % 2)
        yield X,y

with K.tf.device('/gpu:2'):
    K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=K.tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False)))
    MINI_BATCH_SIZE = 64
    PATCH_SIZE = 100
    model = make_model(PATCH_SIZE)
    gen = dummy_generator(mini_batch_size=MINI_BATCH_SIZE,block_size=PATCH_SIZE)
    model.fit_generator(gen, MINI_BATCH_SIZE*10,
                        100, verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[],
                        validation_data=None,
                        nb_val_samples=None,
                        max_q_size=1,
                        nb_worker=1, pickle_safe=False)
```

For the 'tf' case this is the training log: (and looks very similar on different seeds):

```
Epoch 1/100
640/640 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.4781     
Epoch 2/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.4938     
Epoch 3/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5203     
Epoch 4/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5469     
Epoch 5/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6935 - acc: 0.4875     
Epoch 6/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6941 - acc: 0.4969     
Epoch 7/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6937 - acc: 0.5047     
Epoch 8/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.5312     
Epoch 9/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6923 - acc: 0.5250     
Epoch 10/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6929 - acc: 0.5281     
Epoch 11/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6934 - acc: 0.4953     
Epoch 12/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6918 - acc: 0.5234     
Epoch 13/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6930 - acc: 0.5125     
Epoch 14/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6939 - acc: 0.4797     
Epoch 15/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.5047     
Epoch 16/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6917 - acc: 0.4922     
Epoch 17/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6945 - acc: 0.4891     
Epoch 18/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6948 - acc: 0.5000     
Epoch 19/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6968 - acc: 0.4594     
Epoch 20/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6919 - acc: 0.5391     
Epoch 21/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6904 - acc: 0.5172     
Epoch 22/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6881 - acc: 0.5906     
Epoch 23/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6804 - acc: 0.6359     
Epoch 24/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6470 - acc: 0.8219     
Epoch 25/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.4134 - acc: 0.9625     
Epoch 26/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2347 - acc: 0.9953     
Epoch 27/100
640/640 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1231 - acc: 1.0000
```

And for the 'th' case the training log is (and looks very similar on different seeds):

```
Epoch 1/100
640/640 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6891 - acc: 0.5594     
Epoch 2/100
640/640 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6079 - acc: 0.7328     
Epoch 3/100
640/640 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.3166 - acc: 0.9422     
Epoch 4/100
640/640 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.1767 - acc: 0.9969
```

I find it suspicious that it's so fast in the tensorflow case, (0s), but after adding debug printing to the generator it does seem to get called.
I thought that maybe it's related to keras not needing to reshape anything, but 2-3 seconds sounds too much time for this amount of reshapes

If anyone can try to reproduce the results that I see and help me understand what the heck am I missing here, I'd be grateful :)

Comment: Have you figure out what it was?

Comment: not yet, was too busy with too many things @pplonski
I'll retry this soon with latest version, thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue using cuda 8.0 and titan x (pascal).

Answer (score 1):

This thread is bit old but I am still replying in case someone faces the same issues.

The error is caused due to the inconsistent Keras backend configuration...

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_dim_ordering": "th"  
}
```

The configuration uses `tensorflow` as backend but uses image dimension ordering of `Theano` instead of `tensorflow`. change `image_dim_ordering` to `tf` and that should solve the issue..

```
"image_dim_ordering": "tf"
```

Comment: I'm well aware of tensorflow and theano image dim ordering, as can be seen by looking at the standalone reproducing code I shared in the question description. This was NOT an issue of misunderstanding image_dim_ordering and keras configuration file.
Look at the few lines that start with "if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':", and see that the code supports any keras configuration.